# Calculate available memory in liunx

Tags: linux, memory

The execution of :-

```
free -k
```

gives following output:-

```
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1863224      966628       94584       88584      802012      620712
Swap:       1048572      167936      880636
```

To find free memory,

```
free = total -(used + buffcache)
free = 1863224 - (966628+802012)
     = 94584 which is correct
```

How to calculate available memory? 
what is the difference between available and free memory?

Comment: This could be your answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413593/what-is-difference-between-total-and-free-memory?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From the `free` manpage:

```
   available
          Estimation  of  how  much  memory  is available for starting new
          applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by  the
          cache  or  free fields, this field takes into account page cache
          and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed
          due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, avail‐
          able on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the
          same as free)
```

So, this is an estimate (not a precise calculated number) derived from the other numbers - it is *roughly* free memory plus free-able buffers/caches.